# Understanding Data Binding from a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to C#/.NET and especially to binding since it is a new concept for me, I do understand simple binding like the one below...

```
<TextBox Name="myTextField" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=myTextField2}" />
<TextBox Name="myTextField2" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=myTextField}"/>
```

But I'm confused on how to do it from a `ViewModel`. I was [watching a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysWK4e2Mtco) about `MVVM` which helped me understand a few concepts that I had trouble understanding, but since no code was provided I tried to write the code to see the demonstration in action but I'm missing the `XAML/Binding` part since the presenter doesn't show that part of the code. You can see how all works in minute `5:05`.

Here is all of the code:

Person Class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MVVM_BestPractices 
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName 
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set 
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName 
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set 
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        public string FullName 
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName); }
        }

        public Person() {}

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName) 
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
        }

        // INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel Class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MVVM_BestPractices {
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Person _model;
        public Person Model 
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set 
            {
                _model = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ViewModel() 
        {
            Model = new Person("Brian", "Lagunas");
        }

        // INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

XAML Code: As you can see I have no clue on how to bind the data from the ViewModel.

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_BestPractices.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_BestPractices"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox  Width="200" Height="30" Margin="158,57,159,233"/>
        <TextBox  Width="200" Height="30" Margin="158,102,159,188"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person, Mode=OneWay}" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="158,148,159,142"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can someone help me bind the data from the ViewModel to the `textBoxes` as shown in minute `5:05`?

This will help me understand `Binding` and `MVVM`.

Comment: You watched one video?  There's a wealth of info out there.  Go read up on the subject.

Comment: I wrote the post [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) specifically to link to from SO for WPF beginners that are strugging to understand the DataContext and how it works in relation to WPF's binding system. I'd highly recommend reading through it :)

Comment: Thank you for the article, it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without watching the video, I would say:

```
<TextBox  Text={Binding Model.FirstName} ... />
<TextBox  Text={Binding Model.LastName} ... />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.FullName, Mode=OneWay}" ... />
```

This ought to work but only because you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your Model class here. You don't always have or want that.

Side note: try to avoid using `Margin=""` for layout purposes. I know that's what the Designer does but it's a really bad practice.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot for the suggestion about not using `Margin` I'm always looking for these off-topic suggestions since they help me a lot to understand new ecosystems. Do you use `HorizontalAlignment and/or VerticalAlignment ` instead?

Comment: No, I use Grid and StackPanel mostly. A good layout should stay consistent when you resize the Window. Avoid dragging with the mouse, it adds all that crud that you have to remove again.

Comment: IMHO, you should use Margin for what its name implies: a small space around your control, but not for placement.

Answer (score 2):

In your ViewModel, you call your property Model, not Person (Person being your type). So you need to change your binding to `{Binding Model, Mode=OneWay}`. The binding will then happen, but you won't have the result (that I guess) you are looking for. What you want to write is not the value of Model (ie Model.ToString()), but the value of the FullName property of Model. So it's quite simple: `{Binding Model.FullName, Mode=OneWay}`

Moreover, in the set of your properties, you should begin with checking if the new value is different from the old one.

```
set
{
    if (_firstName == value) return;
    _firstName = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName)); // And use nameof() like this if you're in C# 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding to the Model property in the ViewModel is straightforward if you have set the DataContext (which you have):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person, Path=FirstName}"/>
```

or you can omit the Path:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}"/>
```